# Why can't we flag as "off topic" for other SE sites?

Tags: support, migration

When we flag as "Off-topic" and suggest another SE site, we can only choose from a couple options. I've been in the situation where I want to flag a post as Android or iDevice, but can't select these sites.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 10):

By default, regular users can only migrate questions to sites which questions occurring on Super User are likely to need to be migrated to. This is for several reasons, but primarily so that questions don't get migrated to the wrong place, and to reduce clutter in the UI.

Moderators (users with a diamond ♦ next to their name) have the ability to migrate questions to any site on the Stack Exchange network. If you think a question belongs on a site not shown in the standard migration dialog, flag it for moderator attention and leave a message stating which site it should be migrated to. Note that questions which are on-topic for another site but are *also* on-topic for Super User will *not* be migrated unless the person who asked the question specifically asks for it to be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

If these come up a lot we can unlock the migration routes to Apple and Android.

However, all 5 migration slots are currently in use, so you would have to make a case that Apple and Android question migrations happen *more than* ...

- gaming
- webapps
- stackoverflow
- serverfault

You tell me -- which is more common?

Comment: I'd say the current slots are fine.

Comment: @sathya I'm curious how many questions were migrated to SO and Gaming in the last, say, 60 days

Comment: from what I recall - webapps gets the highest number of migrations, followed by SO, SF, Apple, Android. You could perhaps switch around SF/Apple slots but that might result in lot of on topic SU questions being migrated to Apple. I can gather some data on this

Comment: Personally, I don't think Apple should be on the default list. There are a lot of apple questions which are perfectly on-topic for Super User which users might mistakenly migrate to Apple.SE. _Some_ question really should be migrated there, but I think that should be a moderator decision. We don't want on-topic questions being moved away unless the asker specifically wants it to be moved so as to get a better response.

Comment: @Sathya, @nhinkle: http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/q/98791/migrations-per-site (not sure how to count the results though...)